# FastAPI depdendency factory

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi

I want to charge some credits for API usage and came up with following dependency

```
def charge_call(cost: int):
    async def _charge_call(
        wallet=Depends(get_wallet),
    ):
        await wallet.charge(cost)

    return _charge_call


@router.post(
    "/some-call",
    dependencies=[Depends(charge_call(10)]
)
```

It works great, but here is a problem. Some endpoints can charge different amount of credits based on Incoming parameters and I tried to create another factory and use it like this, but it never calls `_charge_call`

```
def charge_test_call(
        call_type: str,
):
    if call_type == "A":
        cost = 1
    else:
        cost = 2
    return charge_call(cost)


@router.post(
    "/test-call",
    dependencies=[Depends(charge_test_call)]
)
async def test_call(
    call_type: str,
):
    if call_type == "A":
        return "A"
    return "B"
```

Is it possible to recursively resolve dependencies in FastAPI or I have to redesign how charging works?

Comment: You might have to be more explicit - i.e. - `call_type: str = Query(...)` to indicate that the value comes from a query variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with [advanced dependency usage](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/). It is taking `call_type` query param and it applies business logic on top.

```py
class WalletChecker:

    async def __call__(self, call_type: str = "A", wallet: Wallet 
 = Depends(get_wallet)):
        if call_type == "A":
            cost = 1
        else:
            cost = 2

        print(f"Cost: {cost}", call_type)
        await wallet.charge(cost)

wallet_checker = WalletChecker()

@router.post(
    "/test-call",
    dependencies=[Depends(wallet_checker)]
)
def test():
    return {"test": "test"}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I want to. I tried to reuse my existed dependency that is suitable for other endpoints.